# Identifying errors in CSV files

Tags: r

Please I am getting errors when I run the codes below on pycharm for R. I need assistance to Identify what is wrong with each of the following inline CSV files.

```
 read_csv("a,b\n1,2,3\n4,5,6")
 read_csv("a,b,c\n1,2\n1,2,3,4")
 read_csv("a,b\n\"1")
 read_csv("a,b\n1,2\na,b")
 read_csv("a;b\n1;3")
```

I executed the first line below is the output

```
 read_csv("a,b\n1,2,3\n4,5,6")
```

Error in read_csv("a,b\n1,2,3\n4,5,6") (Week 1.R#113): could not find function "read_csv"
Show stack trace

Comment: You may need to load `library(readr)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use `readr::read_csv`.